# Embedded For Loop in If Statement Conditional Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, radio-button

When trying to to make sure that at least radio button for each question in my quiz (what I'm making) has been checked before allowing a user to submit, I used a for loop inside an if statement conditional. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<form name="quizform">
            <div id="quizpart1">
                <h2>Title</h2>
                <br>
                <div id="notfinished1">
                </div>
                <br>
                    <!---Question 1: --->
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-8">
                            <label>1) Have you ever ...?</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input type="radio" name="heartAttack?" value="true">Yes</input>
                            <br>
                            <input type="radio" name="heartAttack?" value="false">No</input>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

And my HTML to create the form is very much similar to the above format for the rest of the questions.

Javascript:

```
//Variables
var quizpart1names = ["heartAttack?", "familyHeartDisease?", "congenitalHeartDisease?", "lungDisease?", "currentHeartThyroidDisease?"];

//If Loop With For as a Conditional
if (
        for (i=0; i < quizpart1names.length; i++){
            $('input[name=quizpart1names[i]]:checked').length > 0;
        }
    ){ //Used the jQuery Function :checked, and the logic behind the .length > 0 is that the "true" and "false" both have lengths > 0.
        $("#quizpart1").hide();
        //... The code goes on, but it works when there is no for loop in the conditional (when I was not checking if all the questions in the quiz I am making were answered.)
```

Unfortunately, in the firefox browser, when I run this webpage, none of the javascript which I wrote (including this example) works anymore. Any insight into this problem would be helpful.

Comment: What's the actual problem?

Comment: @Popnoodles In firefox, the page doesn't load correctly,  and essentially all the javascript which I wrote stops working.

Comment: @Popnoodles He has his `for` loop where the condition is supposed to go in `if( /* condition */ )`

Comment: You can't include a for loop within a condition. It's a syntax error, and stops the executioning of your code. What exactly you're trying to implement? Notice, that `if` is not a loop, it's a condition statement executed only once.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be useful.

Comment: @Teemu there's not enough info given in the question for it to be an accurate enough answer. If the question is completed, I'll restore it.

Comment: @Popnoodles The answer which you gave before worked perfectly. There was no need to take it off.

Comment: Even if your question does get answered, in order for it to be useful in the future you should [edit] your question to turn your code into a [mcve] which reproduces the issue that you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use statements (`for`) inside an expression.

You can use the `grep` method to filter out items where the condition is true, and then check how many there are left.

If you wany any of the conditions to be true:

```
if (
  $.grep(quizpart1names, function(q){
    return $("input[name='" + q + "']:checked").length > 0;
  }).length > 0
) {
  ...
}
```

If you want all of the conditions to be true:

```
if (
  $.grep(quizpart1names, function(q){
    return $("input[name='" + q + "']:checked").length > 0;
  }).length == quizpart1names.length
) {
  ...
}
```